# Webpack injecting wrong file names

Tags: javascript, webpack, webpack-config

Webpack is injecting script file names into my HTML file that are different from the names of the files it is actually generating.

I have a home page HTML file with these script tags:

```
<script src="../../node_modules/systemjs/dist/system.src.js"></script>
<script src="systemjs.config.js"></script>
```

When Webpack runs, it replaces these with:

```
<script src="85761405769dc8200d72.js"></script>
<script src="60b468ae637714521bff.js"></script>
```

But no files with these names are generated. Instead, the files it is actually outputting to the \dist folder are:

```
ca85d1be53e78eca8867.js
a2c8e7797f575befb909.js
```

So, I get **404 Not Found** errors when the browser tries to load the files referenced in the HTML file.

My entry and output configuration is:

```
    entry: {
      polyfill: ["core-js/stable", "regenerator-runtime/runtime"],
      home: "./src/home/home.ts",
    },
    output: {
      devtoolModuleFilenameTemplate: "webpack:///[resource-path]?[loaders]",
      clean: true,
    },
```

The HtmlWebpackPlugin configuration is:

```
new HtmlWebpackPlugin({
   filename: "home.html",
   template: "./src/home/home.html",
   chunks: ["polyfill", "home"],
}),
```

Any ideas on why mismatched file names are being created?

Or, failing that, is there any way to get Webpack to just leave the original `<script>` tags as they are?

Comment: Do you get a 404 locally or when deployed to a prod environment (or both)?

Comment: @ksav Both. (BTW, what would be the significance if it was only, say, local?)

Comment: No. I never did.